# XCTest test failing, with no code in body

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xcode7

I am trying to create unit tests for my framework. I've created a 'Unit Testing Bundle' target and have my test class compiled in the target.

My test class extends XCTestCase.

I've left `func testExample()` empty, but still the test is failing. Why is this?

[image]

Comment: It's not returning `true`; uncomment `XCTAssert(true)`.

Comment: Is there anything in /Applications/Utilities/Console.app regarding your test run? Sometimes Xcode will fail a test run mysteriously and not populate any error information in the app itself, but only log things.

Comment: It's not supposed to return anything, it's a `void` function. Returning anything creates a compile-time error. `XCTAssert` doesn't return anything, it checks if a statement is `false` and then throws an exception, otherwise does nothing. Asserting something `false` is supposed to fail a test, which is what I was trying to test but even asserting `true` fails, as well as no code, which is my issue

Comment: @mz2 here is my [console output when I run the test](http://i.imgur.com/4JQ5ZiR.png). It seems like the file is getting a bad file descriptor, but I'm not too familiar with this end